# how to go to another page when clicking on Alert Box in selenium Webdriver by using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I opened my Alert Box then i wanted to move to Shopping List but i am not able to reach Shopping List Page, My code is -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/button[2]")).click();
     Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     alert.accept(); 
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Shopping List")).click();
```

It shows same error again and again, I used more and more code but could not find any solution , Please help me Tester...

No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait till alert is popped up:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
.ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```